# What is the time complexity of zip() in Python?

Tags: python, time-complexity

How can I calculate the time complexity of zip()?

```
testList = [[1,2,3]for _ in range(5)]
zip(*testList)
```

Comment: its O(N*M) where N is the length of the shortest list and M is the number of lists

Comment: you will need to distinguish whether you are using python 2 or python 3 as `zip` has different functionality in both.

Comment: the call itself i guess is O(1) in python 3 ... but the evaluation remains the same I think ... maybe Im totally wrong though

Comment: Have you tried running some tests with varying data sizes?

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen Ya, you are right. I ran these codes in python 2.7 which will return a list.

Comment: If you don't believe Tamas, you can check the source yourself https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c (in py2 izip == zip in py3). It doesn't even check the length of the iterable, just the number of iterables there are

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assume you zip N iterables.

In **python 3.x**, the zip function itself runs in `O(1)` time, as it just allocates a special iterable (called the zip object), and assigns the parameter array to an internal field. The function invocation itself (before control reaches in zip) is `O(N)`, as the interpreter must convert the parameters to an array. Every subsequent `next` call on the iterator also runs in `O(N)`. Exhausting the zip object is therefore `O(N*M)` assuming M is the average (or minimum) length of the iterables, excluding the time the iterables themselves take to generate items (as it is independent of zip).

In **python 2.x**, the zip function returns a list. That list must be constructed during the call, that is equvivalent to exhausting the iterator in the previous example, so `O(N*M)`, not counting the time spent in the zipped iterables.

Comment: Statement `c = list(zip(a, b))` has `O(min(len(a), len(b)))` time complexity. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: And what is the space complexity of a zip function? I guess it's O(1)?