# Time complexity of code snippet in Python including zip(a,b)

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

First of all, I know that similar questions have been asked about this in [What is the time complexity of zip() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877715/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-zip-in-python) and [Time Complexity for Python Zip Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994204/time-complexity-for-python-zip-function) and the answers have helped me a bit but not entirely, so I just want to make sure that I understood things right.

The following are variables in my script:

- `s` and `L`: some pre-defined integers,
- and `orig_vecs`: a pre-defined list of lists, more specifically a list with `L`lists of size `s` each. I like to look at it as an L x s matrix with L vectors of size s.

**Goal**: Remove the last element of each of the `L` vectors, and store that as a different list of lists of size L x (s-1). I call this list `edit_vecs` in the code snippet below. I would like to confirm two things with you:

1. that my time complexity analysis of this code snippet is correct;
2. whether there is a better/more efficient way of doing this from a complexity standpoint.

```
(... some previous code ...)

edit_vecs = [[1] * (s - 1) for _ in range(L)] # generates the list of lists with the desired shape

i = 0
for v in orig_vecs: # L iterations
    v.pop()
    edit_vecs[i] = [a * b for a, b in zip(edit_vecs[i], v)] 
    i += 1

(... some ensuing code ...)
```

Analyzing this snipped this is my reasoning:

1. `edit_vecs = [[1] * (s - 1) for _ in range(L)]`: takes O(L*(s-1)) time
2. `v = orig_vec[i].pop()` : popping the last element of a list takes O(1) time
3. `edit_vecs[i] = [a * b for a, b in zip(edit_vecs[i], v)]`  there is a lot going on here:

   - from previous questions I interpret that zip(,) takes O(1) time to create the iterator but then since I am looping through it this list comprehension should take O(s-1) time;
   - the assignment requires an additional O(s-1) time; (is this true?)
   - so overall this line takes O((s-1)^2) time. (?)
4. In the end the total cost of the loop is O(L*(s-1)^2). (?)

I feel like there might be something wrong in this because I have the feeling that there might be a more efficient way of doing things from a complexity theory standpoint, but I am not sure. It would be great if you could help me out.

PS: Part of the difficulty in understanding the previous answers has to do with language. I am not exactly a python "expert" nor do I come from a complexity theory background, so if you could try to simplify the explanations as much as possible it would be very much appreciated.

Also, I am using Python 3.7.

Thanks a lot!

---

**EDIT:**
I apologize if the formulation was confusing. I have now changed the title, and here I provide an minimal reproducible example of what I want to do:

```
import random

s = 20  # size of each vector
L = 5  # number of vectors in the list of lists
orig_vecs = []
for i in range(L):
    orig_vecs.append([random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(s)])
print('Original vectors: ', orig_vecs)

edit_vecs = [[1] * (s - 1) for _ in range(L)]
i = 0
for v in orig_vecs:  # L iterations
    v.pop()
    edit_vecs[i] = [a * b for a, b in zip(edit_vecs[i], v)]
    i += 1

print('Edited vectors: ', edit_vecs)
```

I hope this helps in clarifying things. At any rate, from @juanpa.arrivillaga 's comment I realize that I am clearly complicating things way more than need be, and that this can be simplified to:

```
import random

s = 20  # size of each vector
L = 5  # number of vectors in the list of lists
orig_vecs = []
for i in range(L):
    orig_vecs.append([random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(s)])
print('Original vectors: ', orig_vecs)

edit_vecs = [vec[:-1] for vec in orig_vecs]

print('Edited vectors: ', edit_vecs)
```

And I understand that `edit_vecs = [vec[:-1] for vec in orig_vecs]` takes time *O(s* * *L)*.

Comment: "the assignment requires an additional O(s-1) time" huh? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: When you write  a question, you **really** should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you clarify just what exactly you are wondering about? In how far do the linked questions *not* answer your question *about the time complexity of ``zip``*? None of your points of confusion seem to be about ``zip``, yet the title is about that. How is the *correctness* of the complexity analysis affected by an *alternative* (possibly more efficient) algorithm?

Comment: `zip(edit_vecs[i], v)` this code doesn't make sense. `v` is an integer here. This would raise an error

Comment: The assignment takes *O(1)* time.

Comment: As for the code, what is ``orig_vecs``? Why does it iterate the ``v``s and also pop them? Why create ``edit_vecs`` upfront when each element gets replaced anyway? It's hard to say how to do something more efficiently when it's not clear what that something even is.

Comment: In any case, all you really need is `edit_vecs = [vec[:-1] for vec in original_vecs]`. This is O(N) *on the total size of the original nested structure*. If I had to guess at what your code was intending to do (what it is currently doing is not correct) then it too would have that same time complexity. Although, you did it in an overly complicated way that also happens to *mutate* the original list unnecessarily

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga O(s-1) is a perfectly valid time complexity, you just wouldn't say that because O(s) is simpler.

Comment: I'm just confused by the last edit. What *is* ``v``? Why would you pop off and discard an element from it? Did you mean to remove ``v`` *from* ``orig_vecs``?

Comment: The are basically doing: `[vec[:-1] for vec in original_vecs]` by first initalizing a list of lists of the right size, but all 1's. Then zipping each row of 1's with the row from the original list that has had an element popped off(mutating it!), i.e. `zip(edit_vecs[i], v)`, so that the resulting row is the same as the modified row. It's a little convoluted